# Class method takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python

please explain where is my error

```
class SomeClass1():
  def func1(self,text):
    .....
class SomeClass2():
   def func2(self):
     a=SomeClass1.func1("string")
```

Gives an error: 
in func2 a=SomeClass1.func1("string"), func1 takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: You're not passing the instance: `SomeClass1().func1("string")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, here's a solution that calls the function through the class, passing an instance as a parameter.

```
class SomeClass2():
   def func2(self):
     obj = SomeClass1()
     a = SomeClass1.func1(obj, "string") # this will help you understand the meaning of `self` as parameters inside those functions.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to call it the same way, you can change func1 like this

```
class SomeClass1():
    @staticmethod
    def func1(text):
        print(text)
```

In this case, 'func1' becomes a static method. This means you don't need to create an instance to call it.